# Tu b'Shvat Prayers by R' Yehuda Halevi (Gaon)

Tags: sources-mekorot, shemoneh-esrei, song-poetry, tu-bishvat, genizah-storage

A number of years ago, they discovered in the Cairo Geniza a number of Piyutim and Prayers for Shemonah Esrei, to be included on Tu b'Shvat. I found this item listed on a Cairo Geniza database, but I'm looking for the actual text. Here is the Geniza listing: http://cudl.lib.cam.ac.uk/bibliographies/genizah/search?query=3882&queryType=TITLEID

I also found a "Rabbi Joyce Galaski" who translated the text into English, contained in a book called "Trees, Earth and Torah: A Tu B'Shvat Anthology". But I have been unable to locate the text itself online.

Does anyone have information on this text, or know where it can be located?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I may have found them myself! To clarify, this is not the [Yehuda HaLevi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Judah_Halevi) of the Kuzari; it is the other Yehuda HaLevi, a student of [Eliezer HaKalir](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eleazar_ben_Killir). They are brought in Sefer [Tehilla L'David](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/20613), a collection of Torah sources on Tu B'Shvat. Here it is: [hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=20613&st=&pgnum=254](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=20613&st=&pgnum=254)

Comment: Hi Chaim. Thanks for coming back to share your answer with us! Now more people who have your question (and even those who didn't) can learn more new things. I hope to see you around :)

Answer (score 2):

Thanks for the link to the Hebrew text - it just came in very handy! Let me add that Galaski's translation is indeed in the JPS-published anthology *Trees, Earth, and Torah*, edited by Ari Elon; I own a paper copy but have also been able to access [the whole of that section](https://books.google.com/books?id=MQ5Z4thHdukC&pg=PA71&lpg=PA71&dq=galaski%20trees%20earth&source=bl&ots=o97bJI_kPl&sig=oI3boDHyKotnngrLJI_UkrWCJS4&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjNofKy0cPKAhUlnIMKHT1_DYEQ6AEIHTAA#v=onepage&q=galaski%20trees%20earth&f=false) on Google Books.